# How to find the longest length of cycle in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be the following graph:

[image]

What is the longest length of a cycle in G?

---

My current answer is ABGFCGHDCBFEA to be the longest cycle (Not sure if its correct yet). And the way I did was just guessing and I do not think it is very reliable and I could make mistakes.

Is there a method or technique that I can use to guarentee that I find the longest lenght of a cycle in a graph?

If there is one, how do I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you can repeat edges but not vertices then it is called a circuit not a cycle. The one you provided uses all of them so it is the longest.

Comment: ohh, ok. I might have misunderstood cycles and circuits. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the standard definition of a cycle, or did you perhaps mean circuit? The standard definition of a cycle is contains only ONE repeated vertex (namely, the first and the last). Thus, since the graph you provide above only has 8 vertices, the longest possible cycle must be, at maximum, a path containing 9 vertices where the first and last are the same. One such cycle would be ABCDHGFEA. There are multiple you can find here.

To specifically answer the question, the longest length of a cycle in $G$ would be the number of edges in the cycle, which in this case is 8.

If you instead meant that you wanted to find the longest circuit, you may have noticed that there are 12 edges in $G$, and so if you are able to find a circuit of length 12, this is maximal, as you have provided.

Comment: ah ok. Thank you for the explanation, I got circuits and cycles mixed up. Thank you again for clarifying.